# Delete query for two way friendship (mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Friendship in my DB is a two way street. Check screenshot:

[image]

So user id 14 and 1 are friends.

I want a query that can be initiated by either party and that deletes two way street completely removing both rows.

How would I go about doing this? This is not simple WHERE asked asker = id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `AND` and `OR` to create a condition from simpler conditions, like

```
(asker_user_id = 14 AND asked_user_id = 1) OR
(asked_user_id = 14 AND asker_user_id = 1)
```

Comment: Why is this better than other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You could combine 2 `IN` conditions, to achieve this.

`DELETE FROM foo WHERE asker_user_id IN (1, 14) AND asked_user_id IN (1, 14)`

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d1866/1

Answer (score 0):

Selfjoin:

```
SELECT *
FROM friendship asker
LEFT JOIN friendship asked
ON asker.asked_user_id = asked.asker_user_id
WHERE asker.asker_user_id IS NOT NULL
```

I cannot test right now (or just lazy to create an sqlfiddle),
but it is something like this.

I maybe switched asked and asker in a way.

This is the way you can test if you have both (instead of select, use delete, **after** checking the correct fields)

Comment: Please argue why this is better than simpler solutions.

Comment: This is a simple solution. To find the best solution, you would use the profiler `EXPLAIN <sql statement>` and see whats the fastest query with least steps and rows looked up.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM friendship
WHERE (asker_user_id = 14 AND asked_user_id = 1)
   OR (asker_user_id = 1 AND asked_user_id = 14)
```

Answer (score 0):

### UPDATED (and tested)

My approach works even if you don't know relationship between 1 and 14. If you are looking for really "(asker = 14 AND asked = 1) OR (asked = 14 AND asker = 1)", it is easy while you are thinking *"This is not simple"*

Here is what I have tested. I hope this help somebody (including OP). Thanks.

**Given Data**

```
CREATE TABLE tab
(
  id int,
  asker_user_id int,
  asked_user_id int
);

insert into tab value(1, 2, 1);
insert into tab value(2, 15, 1);
insert into tab value(3, 14, 1);
insert into tab value(4, 1, 14);
insert into tab value(5, 5, 1);
insert into tab value(6, 1, 5);
insert into tab value(7, 2, 5);
```

**Q1 - find all relationship**

```
SELECT t1.asker_user_id, t1.asked_user_id
FROM tab AS t1 JOIN tab AS t2
  WHERE t1.asked_user_id = t2.asker_user_id
    AND t2.asked_user_id = t1.asker_user_id
+---------------+---------------+
| asker_user_id | asked_user_id |
+---------------+---------------+
|             1 |            14 |
|            14 |             1 |
|             1 |             5 |
|             5 |             1 |
+---------------+---------------+
```

**Q2 - before delete, check relationship's record id**

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.id as record_id
FROM tab A JOIN 
(
    // insert Q1 here
) B ON (A.asker_user_id = B.asker_user_id AND A.asked_user_id = B.asked_user_id)
       OR (A.asked_user_id = B.asker_user_id AND A.asker_user_id = B.asked_user_id)
+-----------+
| record_id |
+-----------+
|         3 |
|         4 |
|         5 |
|         6 |
+-----------+
```

**Q3 DELETE all friendship record**

```
DELETE A
FROM tab A JOIN 
(
    // insert Q1 here
) B ON (A.asker_user_id = B.asker_user_id AND A.asked_user_id = B.asked_user_id)
       OR (A.asked_user_id = B.asker_user_id AND A.asker_user_id = B.asked_user_id)

Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.00 sec) <== records which has friendship are deleted.
```

### Orig. Answer

Not tested, but I guess it will display both 13 and 14

```
SELECT *
FROM tab A JOIN 
(
    SELECT t1.asker_user_id, t2.asked_user_id
    FROM tab AS t1 JOIN tab AS t2
      WHERE t1.asked_user_id = t2.asker_user_id
        AND t2.asked_user_id = t1.asker_user_id
) B ON (A.asker_user_id = B.asker_user_id AND A.asked_user_id = B.asked_user_id)
  OR A.asked_user_id = B.asker_user_id AND A.asker_user_id = B.asked_user_id)
```

when above query works, then delete like this:

```
DELETE FROM tab
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT A.id
    FROM tab A JOIN 
    (
        SELECT t1.asker_user_id, t2.asked_user_id
        FROM tab AS t1 JOIN tab AS t2
          WHERE t1.asked_user_id = t2.asker_user_id
            AND t2.asked_user_id = t1.asker_user_id
    ) B ON (A.asker_user_id = B.asker_user_id AND A.asked_user_id = B.asked_user_id)
      OR A.asked_user_id = B.asker_user_id AND A.asker_user_id = B.asked_user_id)
)
```

Comment: Please tell me why this is better than simpler solutions here?

Comment: Hey, can you take a look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20456030/creating-friends-timeline-similar-to-facebook-mysql-query

Answer (score 0):

```
$slq = "SELECT * from Table where `id` = '13' "; //depending on user
$query = mysql_query($sql);
$result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$asker = $result['asker_user_id']; //14 //
$asked = $result['asked_user_id']; //1
$id = $result['id'];

$del_sql = "DELETE from table WHERE asked_user_id = '.$asker.' AND asker_user_id = '.$asked.'";
$del_query = mysql_query($del_sql);
$del_first = "Delete from table Where `id` = $id";
$del_first_query = mysql_query($del_first);
```